# CSS: Is clear both need in different level of div

Tags: css, css-float

I have this `CSS` code:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
}

#col1 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#col2 {
    width: 600px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px;
}

#col3 {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background: black;
    clear: both; **<~ This**
}
```

`HTML` code:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
    <div id="col3"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Question:
Is the propertie `clear: both` need in `footer` in case of `footer` different level with `colx` (col1, col2, col3)?

Comment: No need for clear both in the #footer. Just add overflow:auto or hidden to #content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are floating elements inside the footer then yes a clear:both may be required.  If you are not floating elements inside the footer then you can take the clear:both out.

Another way to deal with floated elements is to use a structure like this:

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="lft">lft</div>
    <div class="rgt">rgt</div>
</div>

.con { overflow:hidden; }
.lft { width:100px; float:left; }
.rgt { width:100px; float:left; }
```